# Agora SDK compatibility with Safari - both macos and ios

Tags: agora.io

I am building a PWA with Agora broadcasting API. I managed to get the video stream playing on desktop Chrome, but not on Safari. The documentation says Safari is supported on both MacOS and iOS, but it doesn't seem like the case.

When I opened the client page on Safari, instead of playing the video stream, it just create a video player without content. I don't see any data being streamed in the inspector view, or there isn't any activity going on at all.

Do I need to do something different with Safari?

Answer (score 3):

Agora.io provided an auto-diagnostic page for their Web SDK, which may be useful for you:

[agora_webrtc_troubleshooting](https://webdemo.agora.io/agora_webrtc_troubleshooting/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried it on Chrome and Safari on my iMac, the test page works fine with Chrome, but not on Safari nor when I switch my Chrome to mobile display mode. Same goes for when I test it on my iPhone. The test results says none of the resolutions is supported, and in the javascript console it keeps getting an uncaught type error in one of the promises, where it says` i.forEach` is not a function.

Comment: Chrome on you smart phone may suffer from permission problems. Have you tried firefox?